# Problem with initialising 2D vector in C++

Tags: c++

I was implementing a solution for [this problem](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1071) to get a feel for the language. My reasoning is as follows:

1. Notice that the pattern on the diagonal is `2*n+1`.
2. The elements to the left and upwards are alternating arithmetic progressions or additions/subtractions of the elements from the diagonal to the boundary.
3. Create a 2D vector and instantiate all the diagonal elements. Then create a dummy variable to fill in the remaining parts by add/subtract the diagonal elements.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const long value = 1e9;

vector<vector<long>> spiral(value, vector<long> (value));
long temp;

void build(){
    spiral[0][0] = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < 5e8; i++){
        spiral[i][i]= 2*i+1;
        temp = i;
        long counter = temp;
        while(counter){
            if(temp % 2 ==0){
                spiral[i][counter]++;
                spiral[counter][i]--;
                counter--;
                temp--;
            }else{
                spiral[i][counter]--;
                spiral[counter][i]++;
                counter--;
                temp--;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    spiral[0][0] = 1;
    build();
    int y, x;
    cin >> y >> x;
    cout << spiral[y][x] << endl;
}
```

The problem is that the programme doesn't output any thing. I can't figure out why my vector won't print any elements. I've tested it with `spiral[1][1]` and all I get is some obscure assembler message after waiting 5 or 10 minutes. What's wrong with my reasoning?

EDIT: Full output is:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: `const long value = 1e9; vector<vector<long>> spiral(value, vector<long> (value));` -- Compute how much heap memory needs to be allocated for all of this data.

Comment: What's `sizeof(vector<long>)` for you? For me, it's `16`. So that `vector<vector<long>> spiral(value, vector<long> (value));` would be at least 14.90 Gigabyte big on my machine. Does your machine have 14.90 GB of spare memory?

Comment: i think you misunderstood the task. You are not supposed to fill a data structure with all entries of the spiral, you just need a single element

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did call build actually. I forgot to add it to the code posted here because I was running tests before. I've changed it in edit.

Comment: Also, it seems that you fell into the trap of many of these online coding questions.  You are attempting to come up with a very naïve solution that is either excessive in space, excessive in time, or both.  The goal of these questions is to see if you come up with a cleverer approach to the problem.

Comment: Please tell us the *complete* and *full* output you get. Copy-paste it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

A `long` is probably 4 or 8 bytes for you (e.g. commonly 4 bytes on Windows, 4 bytes on x86 Linux, and 8 bytes on x64 Linux), so lets assume 4. `1e9 * 4` is 4 gigabytes of continuous memory for each `vector<long> (value)`.

Then the outer vector creates another `1e9` copies of that, which is 4 exabytes (or 4 million terabytes) given a 32bit long or double for 64bit and ignoring the overhead size of each `std::vector`. It is highly unlikely that you have that much memory and swapfile, and being a global this is attempted *before main() is called*.

So you are not going to be able to store all this data directly, you will need to think about what data actually needs to be stored to get the result you desire.

---

If you run under a debugger set to stop on exceptions, you *might* see a `std::bad_alloc` getting thrown, with the call stack indicating the cause (e.g. Visual Studio will display something like "dynamic initializer for 'spiral'" in the call stack), but it is possible on Linux the OS will just kill it first, as Linux can over-commit memory (so `new` etc. succeeds), then when some program goes to use memory (an actual read or write) it fails (over committed, nothing free) and it SIGKILL's something to free memory (this doesn't seem entirely predictable, I copy-pasted your code onto Ubuntu 18 and on command line got "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'").

Answer (score 0):

Math is your friend, here, not `std::vector`. One of the constraints of this  puzzle is a memory limit of 512MB, but a vector big enough for all the tests would require several GB of memory.

Consider how the square is filled. If you choose the *maximum* between the given `x` and `y` (call it `w`), you have "delimited" a square of size w<sup>2</sup>. Now you have to consider the outer edge of this square to find the actual index.

E.g. Take x = 6 and y = 3. The maximum is 6 (even, remember the zig zag pattern), so the number is (6 - 1)<sup>2</sup> + 3 = 28

```
 *  *  *  *  *  26 
 *  *  *  *  *  27
 *  *  *  *  * [28] 
 *  *  *  *  *  29
 *  *  *  *  *  30
36 35 34 33 32  31
```

[Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PgTnsSVjX2YSSwnN), a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually asks you to find an analytical formula for the solution, not to simulate the pattern. All you need to do is to carefully analyze the pattern:

```
unsigned int get_n(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) {
    assert(row >= 1 && col >= 1);

    const auto n = std::max(row, col);
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        std::swap(row, col);
    if (col == n)
        return n * n + 1 - row;
    else
        return (n - 1) * (n - 1) + col;
}
```